# What colour is Zem the mattress in "Life, the Universe, and Everything?"

Tags: the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy

In [*Life, the Universe and Everything*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1634), a population of mattresses, all called Zem, happily lives on the planet Sqornshellous Zeta. Do we have details, or reasonable intuition, about their color?

The planet itself is described as swampy, covered in dust and with frequent rain. We know that once caught and dried, the mattresses are white and rigid. However, nothing prevents the Zem population to be either brownish or yellowish or, for what I know, furry and pink - any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Zem has blue and white stripes:

> Its **blue and white stripes** glistened briefly in a sudden feeble ray of sun that had unexpectedly made it through the mist, causing the creature to bask momentarily.
>
> *Life, the Universe, and Everything*, Chapter 9

Comment: All mattresses on Sqornshellous Zeta have blue and white stripes. They all look the same and they all have the same name, so none of them are missed when one is caught, gutted, and dried to be used as a mattress.

Comment: Pretty standard appearance for a cheap mattress.